# My Xdebug is not working. Why isn't break points not working?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I have installed Xdebug with VS Code and Flywheel local and I am learning how to make themes. I have put a breakpoint in my index.php file. However, the said breakpoint is not working.

I am not getting any errors in my console. Nothing is happening in VS Code debug terminal when I load my site. It's just all blank. I have also installed PHP Debug extension in VS Code.

However, when I type in debug console anything I get this message - Cannot evaluate code without a connection.

What went wrong here?

My php.ini

```
[xdebug]
{{#if os.windows}}
zend_extension = php_xdebug.dll
{{else}}
zend_extension = {{extensions.xdebug}}
{{/if}}

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=Off
xdebug.remote_port="9000"
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.mode=debug
```

My launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        


        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "pathMappings": {
                "C:/Users/ajayb/Local Sites/wordpress-theme-1/app/public": "${workspaceRoot}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your Xdebug config looks weird, you're using Xdebug2 and Xdebug3 settings at the same time. We don't know which version you're using. If you're using Xdebug3 then replace `xdebug.remote_port` with `xdebug.client_port`. Check this link https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same problem. Local by **FlyWheel** installs **Xdebug 2.7** for **PHP 7.3** and **XDebug 3.x** when using **PHP 7.4**. If you are using **PHP 7.4** modify the **php.ini** file and replace the xdebug section with the following:

```
[Xdebug]

; Consider checking php_xdebug.dll file properties to get installed Xdebug version
zend_extension="D:\Programs\xammp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"

; Settings for Xdebug 2.x
xdebug.scream = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.show_local_vars = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1

; Settings for Xdebug 3.x
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_port="9000" ; Default now is 9003
```

Comment: Thank you!! It's working now. This is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Even if you have XDebug's version 2.x.x, the default configuration is not enough.

You have to use the following for Xdebug v2.x.x:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, as it was mentioned in a comment the main reason is https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

I had the same issue with PHPStorm & Flywheel Local app v6+.
I set PHP 7.4.1 in Local and found in `~/projects/project-name/conf/php/php.ini.hbs` next v2 options:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=Off
xdebug.remote_port="9000"
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
```

But when I checked `var_dump(phpversion('xdebug'));` it ouptuted XDebug 3. It worked for me with v3 options:

```
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
xdebug.client_port="9003"
xdebug.discover_client_host=0
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that i **wasnt changing the php.ini in the right place**.
There is a general conf\php folder and there are version specific ones.
Changing php.ini **xdebug settings in conf\php** solved it.

Also i put the full path in the pathmappings(launch.json) like so:

```
"pathMappings": {
                "C:\\Users\\Test\\Local Sites\\localtest\\app\\public": "${workspaceFolder}",
            }
```